# How to pass a parameter from iframe to iframe?

Tags: javascript, jsp, iframe

I have a parent jsp called parent.jsp. This spawns an iframe called iframe1, which in turn frames an iframe called iframe2 .

From parent.jsp :

```
<iframe id="iframe1" style="display:none;" height="430" 
width="675" 
src="iframe1.jsp?myNumber=<%= bean.getMyNumber() %>" >
```

here, i get the mynumber in iframe1.jsp using :

```
String myNumber=request.getParameter("myNumber");
```

Now i need to pass it again to iframe2.jsp. For that i am calling a javascript method called : createSecondIframe(). Here i am using it like this :

```
createSecondIframe(myNumber)
{
ifrm.setAttribute("src", "iframe2.jsp?myNO=myNumber");
}
```

Here the iframe2 is getting created with all the visual content but the myNumber is not getting passed for when i do this :

```
System.out.println("MyNo::"+request.getParameter("myNO"));
```

I get, MyNO as null.

**EDIT :**

According to Bruno's suggestion , this the function calling createSecondIframe() :

```
function iframe1(myNumber)
{
var parentDynamicDiv = window.parent.document.getElementById('overlay1');
var iframe = window.parent.document.getElementById('container1');

iframe.style.display = 'none';
parentDynamicDiv.style.display = 'none';
createSecondIframe(myNumber);
}
```

Where i am going wrong? Kindly help .

Comment: Try use AJAX instead of playing with iframes. It will cause more problems than you expect, such as browser domain check.

Comment: Yeah, i can't exactly do that, as the requirements are specific to the point of asking an iframe to be used above all.

Comment: instead to do it in JSP, do it in JavaScript, with help of jQuery. Just call parent JavaScript function to change the src URL of 2nd iframe.

Comment: I am surprised you get the script to load the iframe content at all. Where is ifrm defined and what does it contain? I would expect parent.document.getElementById("iframe1").src=...

Comment: As i mentioned earlier, my friend, i cannot change the frame work, which is currently in use, I have to abide by what is there. Hence, i cannot do that as well.

Comment: The iframe contains a text box and some content. Its the text box that needs to be populated with the value. So any one have any ideas as to what am i doing wrong while passing the variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser knows nothing about `myNumber` which exists in context of servlet. You have to explicitly define it somewhere inside client code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myNumber = <%= myNumber %>; 
</script>

createSecondIframe(num)
{
ifrm.setAttribute("src", "iframe2.jsp?myNO="+ num);
}
```

And later call `createSecondIframe` with `myNumber`

```
createSecondIframe(myNumber)
```

Comment: Ok , first, cant really use bean here in iframe1.jsp, as i am already using it in parent.jsp and passing that value as a parameter and catching it in iframe1.jsp, which is working quite well. After passing the variable in the second url for the second iframe, when i try to get it, i am not getting it. Yes i am passing the variable via method argument only and then sending it as : "iframe2.jsp?myNO="+ num . Still i am getting null. Just can;t figure out, what is going wrong .

Comment: Well, try to check if `num` in actually something valid.
For example append `alert(num);` to `createSecondIframe` body

Comment: "cant really use bean here in iframe1.jsp". Try `myNumber` instead. I've edited the code.

Comment: I have done that already, but this is strange. I have given alerts in the methods as you suggested, but the alerts are not popping up. However, the flow of the program is correct since, all the functionalities are working as expected apart from the variable passing .

Comment: Try adding alert before line where you change iframe src.

Comment: Okay did that, but the alert's not coming. I am gonna go mad over this :)

Comment: Just means that the function is probably not running. Do you have any errors in your browser console.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the myNO variable but are specifying myNO as a string. Try this

```
createSecondIframe(myNumber)
{
    ifrm.setAttribute("src", "iframe2.jsp?myNO=" + myNumber);
}
```

Comment: Did it, but no change, still getting null

Comment: Any chance you could show us the code that is calling the `createSecondIframe` function.

Comment: Ok, Edited and provided the method which calls the createSecondIframe() method .

Comment: @TheDarkKnight Also check that the number being passed into function `iframe1` is not null or undefined or anything you wouldn't expect.