# How do I send value from child page to parent page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page named `parent.html`. From there I call a modal dialog `child.html`.
I have a link button in `child.html` to close the modal dialog. At the same time I want to pass value from `child.html` to `parent.html`.

How do I send the value from the child page to the parent page?

Comment: Look this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13561033/how-to-pass-a-parameter-from-iframe-to-iframe/13562677#13562677

Answer (score 2):

If your child page (child.html) is located at same domain as parent page, you can call a parent window's function from child.html.

In the child page (child.html) :

```
<a href="..." onclick="parent.callFromChildPage('ABC')">Button Title</a>
```

And, In the parent page (parent.html) :

```
<script language="javascript">
function callFromChildPage(a_value){
    alert("A value from child window is :" + a_value); // 'ABC'
}
</script>
```

And also, if you can use jQuery in the child page (child.html), you can set　parent page's element directly as follows:

```
<a href="..." onclick="$('#test', window.parent.document).html('ABC');">Button Title</a>
```

Comment: "window.parent" object is the officially supported Document Object Model (DOM).
Please see here:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_parent.asp
And here : 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.parent

Please note that the parent.html and child.html are needed to be exsit on the same domain.
If not, the access is regarded as a kind of Cross Site Scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Basically define a javascript function in the parent page, then in the child page simply call this function by using `opener`.

[window.opener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.opener) lets you reference to the window object of the opening document.

Child HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('a#child-link').click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          var tmp = $('input#child-input').value();
          window.opener.getChildVar(tmp);
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" name="child-text" id="child-input" value="test text" />
    <a href="#" id="child-link">link</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Parent HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function getChildVar(val) {
        var received_val = val;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
</html>
```